# Does the von Neumann algebra generated by a normal operator contain all commuting projections?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T\in B(H)$ a bounded normal operator.
Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the von Neumann algebra generated by $T$. Is it true that $\mathscr{A}$ contains every orthogonal projection which commutes with $T$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For instance, if $T$ is the identity operator, then $\mathscr{A}$ is just the span of $T$, but every orthogonal projection commutes with $T$.